# Error al Serializar objetos en la SD

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo que guardar un `array` en la sd pero no hay manera, no me da ningún error simplemente no escribe. Os dejo mi código:

```
private ArrayList<Cuadros> datos = new ArrayList();
private ListView listCuadros;
private AdaptadorCuadros adaptador;
private Context contexto;
private int i = 0;
private EditText titulo;
private EditText autor;
private EditText estilo;
private EditText precio;
private EditText fecha;
private TabHost tabs;
private Cuadros seleccionado;
private Button guardar;
private Button sd;
private int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 0;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


  public void salvarNotaSD() {
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Se necesita acceso de escritura a la SD",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                } else {
                    escribirSD(datos);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "La memoria externa no está disponible",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                        escribirSD(datos);
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(this, "No se ha aceptado el permiso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                default:
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }


        private void escribirSD(ArrayList<Cuadros> datos) {
            try {
                File memExt = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File fichero = new File(memExt.getAbsolutePath(), "/fichero.dat");
                ObjectOutputStream ficheroSalida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fichero));
                ficheroSalida.writeObject(datos);
                ficheroSalida.flush();
                ficheroSalida.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Los datos fueron grabados correctamente en la SD",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

El `salvarnotasd` esta en un `listener onclick` con un botón enlazado, tiene los permisos de escritura en el `manifest`, y tengo implementado `serializable` en la clase `Cuadros` que seria de lo que esta compuesto mi `array`, y no se si seria necesario también implementarlo en la clase adaptadora o no.

He depurado y se queda en esta linea, de ahí salta a la excepción

```
ObjectOutputStream ficheroSalida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fichero));
```

Os he dejado los atributos de la clase para que veáis que tiene y el principio del `oncreate`

error es  `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/ichero.dat: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  para agregar el mensaje de error que está arrojando. Gracias.

Comment: Lo unico que me dice   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/ichero.dat: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: El nombre es incorrecto "ichero.dat", debe ser "fichero.dat" , vuelve a subir tu aplicaciòn ya que en el còdigo es correcto el nombre. Asegura el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Answer (score 0):

El error `FileNotFoundException` puede ocurrir por dos causas:

- **No se tiene aceptado el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` en tu aplicaciòn. Recuerda que este permiso tambien debe definirse dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` .** No es necesario requerir el permiso `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.
- **El archivo que se intenta leer no existe, puede ser que el nombre o la ruta sean incorrectos.**

En este caso puedes ver que el error indica que no encuentra un archivo "ichero.dat", el nombre es incorrecto,

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/ichero.dat: open
>   failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

te sugiero volver a subir tu aplicacion ya que en el codigo es correcto el nombre.

Answer (score 0):

EL error era el emulador tenia android 10 y los permisos alli van diferentes